# React ApexCharts wont show categories data on X-axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, apexcharts

### Explanation

I am using redux to update the values provided to chart in React JS web panel. The problem is when I shift from time series to category the categories on x-axis disappear.

This is my code.
Component.js

`<Chart options={this.props.options} series={this.props.series} type="area" height="387" />`

In the reducer, I change my data like this,

```
      console.log(action.categories); //categories in chart
      console.log(action.chartData); //series component in chart
      return { ...state,
        unique_visitors: action.payload,
        loading_unique_visitors: false,
        chartData: action.chartData,
        timeData: action.timeData,
        categories: action.categories,
        options: {
          ...state.options,
          xaxis: {
            ...state.options.xaxis,
            categories: action.categories,
            type: _.isEmpty(action.categories) ?  'datetime' : '',
          }
        },
        series: [{ name: 'unique visitors', data: action.chartData }]
      };
```

I logged the series object and categories object sent to Chart component, the chart is supposed to update according to the period selected, monthly, weekly, so on.

[image: Screenshot 2019-07-06 at 2 17 52 PM]
Categories object is empty and the latter is series object data.
[image: Screenshot 2019-07-06 at 2 21 44 PM]
This shows the graph.

[image: Screenshot 2019-07-06 at 2 16 08 PM]
This shows the logged categories object and series object
[image: Screenshot 2019-07-06 at 2 16 31 PM]
Here the x-axis elements(categories) won't show. When done statically I can see the x-axis elements.

Comment: Can you please share any working code sample, on codesandbox or anything similar

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @LukeBrown as a matter of fact I did. Just check the examples shown in the library docs. The data needs to be in the exact format. I needed to do some manipulation in the JSON data coming from backend and voila it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone sees this, i had the same issue and as Divye has suggested, it is indeed the format of the JSON > Object > Arrays. Mine, although numeric values, were actually a string and when i converted them using the below, the chart updated as expected.

```
// set up array
let flow = []
// extract the key data from the JSON
Object.entries(JSONDATA.OBJECT).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          // console.log(key)
          flow.push(value)
          // console.log(`${key} ${value}`)
        })
// CONVERT TO INT
flow = flow.map(Number)
```